# Declared Hello World DLL File. External Function Not Found at run-time

Tags: c++, dll, lotus-notes, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

Originally posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617735/declared-dll-but-errors-external-function-not-found) but was informed to not use a class nor namespace. Reposting a simpler example that I still can't get to work.

DLL made with C++ (Visual Studio):

```
// myFirstDLL.h
#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)

DECLDIR int GIMMEFIVE();



// myFirstDLL.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myFirstDLL.h"
#include <stdexcept>

//using namespace std;

int GIMMEFIVE()
{
    return 5;
}
```

LotusScript Agent:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Declare Public Function GIMMEFIVE Lib "P:\Internet\dplows\visualstudio\myFirstDLL\myFirstDLL\Debug\myFirstDLL.dll" () As Integer

Sub Initialize
    MsgBox GIMMEFIVE()

End Sub
```

Comment: What calling convention is expected by lotus script?

Comment: @Niall, it's very similar to VB. Just FYI, I've successfully called functions from a DLL before (flashing the current window in the taskbar via user32.dll). Must just be something wrong with mine.

Comment: [This may help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_WORKING_WITH_EXTERNAL_C_LANGUAGE_FUNCTIONS.html). You may also want to use Dependency Walker to view the name of the exported function. I don't know louts script, but VBA could  be fussy over the function names (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235591(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: This blog post has more detail on the calling conventions etc. (https://www.triplewhitefox.com/tech-calling-c-api-from-lotusscript)

Comment: Solved. Just needed to wrap in an "extern" block. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe not change the question, but type it up as an answer to this question. I'm sure you won't be the last person to have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The function is required to be wrapped in `extern "C"` block;

```
extern "C"
{
    extern __declspec(dllexport) int GIMMEFIVE();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as both `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)`. If you're not calling the function yourself from your DLL, you don't need to forward declare it. You can do it all inline:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GIMMEFIVE()
{
    return 5;
}
```